# How can I target first and last item in a grid row of dynamic entries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

Here are the tools I am using:

- Vuejs
- Jquery Packery with masonry layout

I am building a page that takes content from json and populates the homepage with posts, products and pages in one loop. Each object in the loop is ordered by date with lodash and gets added into the page once a user creates a new post, product or page in the backend.

When clicking on a product it will open info and a content box next to its container with product info. Because of the nature of the interaction I need to make sure I only target divs that are at the far left and right of the rows. I am using Vue JS to render the content in a component. below is an illustration of what I am working with:

[image]

As you can see here, I only want to be able to target css on any items that are at the far left or right if the middle column. The trouble is the content is dynamic and its flowing left to right.

Here is the markup/html I am using:

```
<div id="start-grid">

      <div class="grid__item grid_item-home large--one-third medium--one-whole no-padding" v-for="(key, index) in productsOrderBy" :class="{ influence: productsOrderBy[index].influence === true, about: productsOrderBy[index].about === true, product_item: productsOrderBy[index].vendor}">

        <div v-if="productsOrderBy[index].vendor" class="shop-item">

          <router-link v-bind:data-id="productsOrderBy[index].id" :to="'/products/'+ index" active-class="active" class="product grow">
            <div class="inner-container relative">
              <div class="pad-normal absolute top-0 left-0 z-2 large--one-whole product-color product-info">
                <p class="univers uppercase smaller body-size">
                  Shop
                 </p>
                <p class="lyon-text">{{productsOrderBy[index].title}}</p>
                <p class="univers uppercase smaller body-size buy">
                  Buy now
                 </p>
              </div>
              <div @click="setActive($event)" v-bind:data-id="productsOrderBy[index].id" class="z-1 relative gallery grow" v-bind:id="productsOrderBy[index].id">
                <img class="scale-with-grid archives-image" v-bind:src="productsOrderBy[index].images[0].src" v-bind:alt="productsOrderBy[index].images[0].id">
              </div>

            </div> 
            <transition 
                  v-if="$route.params.id == index"
                  appear
                  name="slide-fade">
                  <div class="absolute z-3 top-0 grid__item large--one-whole card">
                    <router-view :key="$route.params.id"></router-view>
                    </div>
                </transition>     
          </router-link>

        </div>

        <div v-else-if="productsOrderBy[index].about" :style="{ 'background-color': '+productsOrderBy[index].tags+' }" class="inner-container relative blog-index__block" :data-color="productsOrderBy[index].tags">

            <div @click="playVideo($event)" class="pad-normal z-1 large--one-whole">
                <p class="univers uppercase smaller body-size">
                  {{ productsOrderBy[index].title }}
                </p>
                <p class="lyon-text" v-html="productsOrderBy[index].content.html">
                  {{ productsOrderBy[index].content.html }}
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div v-else class="inner-container relative blog-index__block" :data-color="productsOrderBy[index].tags">

              <div class="pad-normal z-1 large--one-whole">
                  <p class="univers uppercase smaller body-size">
                    Influence
                  </p>
                  <p class="lyon-text">
                    {{ productsOrderBy[index].title }}
                  </p>
              </div>

              <img class="scale-with-grid archives-image" v-bind:src="productsOrderBy[index].media.image">

        </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Can anyone see how this can be achieved?

I have looked at nth-child, nth-of-type but they do not work because the content is dynamic so I have thought it might be achievable through Javascript instead by counting the items.

Comment: I need HTML structure for solve this. You can use selector:last-child, selector:first-child

Comment: Just edited it for you to see

Comment: I need the output HTML..

Answer (score 0):

Could you expand a little bit on what you mean by dynamic? Because you can certainly select based on your image with `nth-child` like in my snippet.

```js
$(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){
  $('.wrap').append('<div class="grid-col"></div>');
 });
});
```

```css
.grid-col {
  height: 200px;
  width: 32.26%;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
}
.grid-col:nth-child(3n+1){
 margin-left: 0;
 background-color: red;
}
.grid-col:nth-child(3n){
 background-color: red;
}
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Add Column</button>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="grid-col blog"></div>
  <div class="grid-col page"></div>
  <div class="grid-col blog"></div>
  <div class="grid-col product"></div>
  <div class="grid-col blog"></div>
  <div class="grid-col page"></div>
  <div class="grid-col blog"></div>
  <div class="grid-col product"></div>
  <div class="grid-col blog"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: By dynamic I mean that some items do not need the click on them they are just images. Its the items that have the class of .product and they appear at anytime.

Comment: So if by that you mean the grid structure should stay the same, then the `nth-child` should still select the correct div. I've updated my snippet to add dynamic columns and you can see the correct divs turning red.

Comment: But they have a class defined on them called .product and they could only appear at the 4th, 6th, 11th or 15th position in the list. The rest could have a class called .blog or .page it changes based on the users edits or changes in the backend

Comment: Apologies, but I guess I am still confused. It doesn't matter where the div is being inserted into the `wrap` element on my snippet. CSS will always select the correct div. If the problem is different classes, create a new class with the `nth-child` selector that all the divs inside the parent element can share.

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying but the issue is when I do the above and the client inserts another product the grid readjusts and the nth-child gets ignored because it's not correct and it does not apply to the .product item that this needs to be targeted on. Also packery resets the order too